# Rails create custom function/method and where to store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my article index page I have a condition to display the number of articles, the grammar in the word 'article' changes based on the number. This works as current. As below:

**view/article/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>All Article Page</h1>

<% if Article.count == 1%>
This blog has <%= Article.public_count %> article so far!
<% elsif Article.count >= 2 %>
This blog has <%= Article.public_count %> articles so far!
<% else %>
<%= Article.public_count %> articles, so lonely :(
<% end %>
```

How would I create a custom method or function to apply the above without having to write it all out repeatedly on different views in the future, adhering to DRY. I am aware of partials but want to know whether there is a more rails-like way to do this considering its a highly opinionated system.

After research its not clear whether it should go in my Article model, config/initializer or in my app/controller.

As an example the method would be something like the below, saved within a file called 'article_count.rb'. Then called within the index view, however nothing happens:

```
def display_article_count_string
  if Article.count == 1
    p "This blog has #{Article.public_count} article so far!"
  elsif Article.count >= 2
    p "This blog has #{Article.public_count} articles so far!"
  else
    p "0 articles, so lonely :("
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple and not to complex logic, view logic can go into the `app/helpers` of your Rails project.

For your articles controller, helper file will live at `app/helpers/articles_helper.rb`

```rb
module ArticlesHelper

  def display_article_count_string
    if Article.count == 1
      p "This blog has #{Article.public_count} article so far!"
    elsif Article.count >= 2
      p "This blog has #{Article.public_count} articles so far!"
    else
      p "0 articles, so lonely :("
    end
  end

end
```

For more common stuff you want to share across different views, `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` is another place.

Tip:
Another useful Rails view helper is the `pluralize(1, 'article')` method. It can help provide singular/plural form of your resource name [More Info](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize)

Answer (score 1):

My tips for your case

**view/article/index.html.erb**

```html
  <h1>All Article Page</h1>
  <%= Article.info_count %>
```

- Article.info_count will call class method inside Article
- this is the reason inside article.rb you have to add self as class method (see below)

inside app/model/article.rb

```rb
  def self.info_count 
    if Article.count.zero? 
      "so lonely :("
    else
      "this blog has #{Article.count} article so far!
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

It should go to locales like this:

```
en:
  article:
    zero: "No articles"
    one: "1 article"
    other: "%{count} articles"
```

and in the view:

```
<%= t('.article', count: Article.count) %>
```

**Edit:**
In the above, probably it's just the `.article` needs to become `article` but try a more explicit way:

```
en:
  articles:
    count:
      zero: "No articles"
      one: "1 article"
      other: "%{count} articles"
```

and

```
<%= t('articles.count', count: Article.count) %>
```

Be sure that the locale key is en.

Here is the documentation:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization

The correct way to do that is with locales instead of methods.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however Rubymine raises a warning for the`.article` portion which states - 'No translations found for ".article"'. When running the view, it only shows 'Article'